# Symmetric power of tautological representation of $U(n)$

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups

Let $S^kV$ be the $k$-th symmetric power of tautological representation of $U(n)$ how to see that it's irreducible? I'm trying to do it using weight, but with no benefits..

Answer (score 2):

A direct argument is possible, but it's a bit messy. It's nicer to work at the Lie algebra level because there it's easier to write down maps that move between weight spaces. An even nicer argument uses [Schur-Weyl duality](https://qchu.wordpress.com/2012/11/13/four-flavors-of-schur-weyl-duality/), which also implies that the exterior powers $\wedge^k V$ are irreducible and a bunch of other nice things.

Comment: But how to do it directly?

Comment: @user2715119: again, it's messy. You reduce to showing that the subrepresentation generated by any weight space is the whole thing. You can do this by finding elements of the Lie algebra that move you between weight spaces and showing that you can reach all of them from any of them. This argument is most familiar for $\mathfrak{sl}_2$ and gets more annoying to do the higher rank you go.